# Performance Regression Testing for GCC

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, performance-testing

I am developing a new target to GCC and have my (cross) compiler toolchain set up. I also have a basic simulator of the hardware I am interested in.

As I make changes to GCC - backend and possibly add some passes as well - what are my options when it comes to ensuring there are no performance regressions. Are there any automated tests / setup already available (ready to download and use) like the gcc testsuite ? gcc testsuite only ensures the functional regression part.

Comment: Build a benchmark suite out of the applications _actual users will run on your target_.  How your new backend/passes perform on arbitrary applications (like the SPEC suite) is much less relevant.